# How to add two more Columns in the USER model in djan

Tags: django

How to add these columns(dob, and one more) in User Model, and if we want to add one or more field like a phone number so can id add to the User model or not ??

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get the post parameters
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        dob   = request.POST['dob']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

        # check for errorneous input
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'This Aadhaar is Already Used')
            return redirect('home')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'This Email is already Used')
            return redirect('home')
        if (pass1 != pass2):
            messages.error(request, " Passwords do not match")
            return redirect('home')

        # Create the user 
        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pass1)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.dob = dob
        myuser.save()
        messages.success(request, "You are successfully registered")
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        return HttpResponse("404 - Not found")
```

Comment: Do not mess with built-in models as you won't be able to easily upgrade Django in the future if you do. Use the _profile model method_ [as described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Comment: So can I do authentication with the user defined model?

Comment: No, you will still use the built-in User model for authentication and your custom model (profile model) for storing extra information. See the answer @FrédéricPerron posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extend the default `User` model using `OneToOneField` and creating another model to add those fields:

For instance, you could do something like this:

```py
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
#  dob = models.CharField()
```

After that, you only need to change the call in your views to this model instead of the `User` one.

Comment: Can I simply copy paste this ?

Comment: Of course, but you will have to change your views a little bit to ensure that your `register` view is creating the `User` along with the `ExtendedUser` model. I suggest you take a look at this [blog post](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/extending-djangos-user-model-with-onetoonefield) for doing that since you will need "signals".

Answer (score 0):

you need to extend django User Model.
There are 4 options to implement it.
Here is a link to do so: [How to extend django user model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)